# Adding columns for group by result values in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Lets say my table like this and the table name is Employee.

```
Employee ID         Name               Age
   1                Dilshan             22
   2                Udara               25
   3                Malith              45
   4                Dilshan             40
```

---

```
select Name,Age from Employee
group by Name,Age;
```

the results will be like this.

```
Dilshan             22
Dilshan             40
Udara               25
Malith              45
```

what i want is to have a separate columns for to show all ages per employee name.
My intended results are like this. I'm using oracle 11g.

```
Name               Age1     Age2
Dilshan             22       40
Udara               25       null
Malith              45       null
```

Comment: Does the output `Name="Dilshan"; Age="22,40"` is safe? If not - does max amount of different ages for separate name exists?

Comment: Actually i tried listagg and i was able to get ""Name="Dilshan"; Age="22,40""". But that is not i want.

Comment: How do you define `AGE1` and `AGE2`?  Why is `AGE1` not '40'?

Comment: That's what i'm confusing. Actually this came as a requirement. Let's say Age1 and Age2 are fixed.

Comment: You want a dynamic PIVOT because you don't know how many employees called Dilshan there will be! However, I'm more curious about why you want this strange result structure?  You could have 10 Dilshans? What is your ultimate goal? What happens if two Dilshans have the same age in years?

Comment: This is just an example. My business requirement is more difference than this. I couldn't expose the real requirement due to some security constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   with cte1 as (
   select min(id) as id
   from Employee e
   group by name
   )

   , cte2 as (
   select e.name, e.Age as Age1, eo.Age as age2, e.id
   from Employee e
   left join Employee eo on e.name = eo.name
   and e.ID <> eo.ID
   )

   select cte2.name, cte2.Age1, cte2.age2
   from cte1
   join cte2 on cte1.id =cte2.ID
```